# Recommendations for Online Shopping Plug-ins for Custom Sites

Tags: .net, e-commerce, shopify

I am looking for recommendations for plug-ins/tools/ideas for selling products on a website that is developed using the .NET framework. Currently, some of the sites my team hosts use a plug-in from Shopify that embeds multiple products on a page, adds them to a cart, then checks them out through the Shopify portal. While Shopify has proven helpful, it is not always reliable (EDIT: Better phrasing: The Buy Button has worked for use well, but we are looking for possible alternatives) and some small nit picky things (such as showing the newest items added to the store being featured) are not possible.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: To clear up some misconceptions by past commenters, I am looking for an alternative to Shopify’s Buy Button feature which I can embed products within sites.

Comment: You are hilarious. Shopify has done billions in transactions and you are saying it is not reliable, and cannot do things? Name one thing not reliable, I am curious to hear about it. I know it is far from perfect as a service, but reliability has never been in question.

Anyway, here is some free, informed advice. Learn how to install an App in your Shopify store. Next, setup a Proxy so you can ask questions using your App. Finally, use that Proxy feature to present the latest greatest products as you see fit on your Shopify store front. Profit.

Comment: @DavidLazar Shopify’s plug-in/embed Buy Button feature has its pros and cons and can be a pain to maintain when it comes to our nit picky needs that arise. In terms of reliability, it’s more page load, maintenance, and limited features(such as limited product category list/queries) aka nit picky things. Maybe reliable wasn’t the right word nor was I not clear in my question which miss lead to your anger (and comedic relief). Defend Shopify as much as you want, I do not care, nor do I have a problem with them, I simply came here for suggestions/alternatives, not to be belittled. Thanks tho.

Comment: Shopify has a complete SDK for you to use, where you can build your own buy buttons.

https://help.shopify.com/en/api/custom-storefronts/js-buy-sdk